# Why is the node title null when it is set in the database?

Tags: drupal, ubercart

On my site, I am looking at the edit page for this node: http://example.com/node/5290027/edit. It shows the title as blank and when I do a `var_dump` of `$node`, the title is NULL. However, in the database, there is a title for that node in table node;

```
mysql> select * from node where nid = 5290027;
+---------+---------+---------+----------+----------------------+-----+--------+------------+------------+---------+---------+----------+--------+------+-----------+----------+
| nid     | vid     | type    | language | title                | uid | status | created    | changed    | comment | promote | moderate | sticky | tnid | translate | keywords |
+---------+---------+---------+----------+----------------------+-----+--------+------------+------------+---------+---------+----------+--------+------+-----------+----------+
| 5290027 | 5289971 | digital | en       | Building Chris Craft |   0 |      1 | 1370006759 | 1370006759 |       0 |       1 |        0 |      0 |    0 |         0 |          |
+---------+---------+---------+----------+----------------------+-----+--------+------------+------------+---------+---------+----------+--------+------+-----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: can you post the var_dump or devel output as well? My hunch would be a permissions/access Issue, or a related if loop within the theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're in a standard node edit form which it looks like you are from the example url you gave, I'd probably start by disabling javascript to make sure this is not cleared out on the client side.

If this is not the case I'd start by looking for any hook_form_alter or hook_form_FORM_ID_alters that relate to this. A quick search would be to search for ['title'] or ["title"] within the modules directory which would return any instances of this being changed within the FAPI.

Comment: Turns out it was changed by another function that hooks into the fapi.